# Change auto generated filename

Tags: php

So I have this PHP-script which is linked to a contact form on one of my clients sites. What the PHP-script does is basically to take all the fields and values and generates a .txt file with the information given in the form. After that the script decides what to name the file depending on what information you add in the field `'forefternamn'`.

My question is pretty straight forward. How do I, instead of naming the file after the field, name it with a serial number?

I would like the serial number to start with 1000 on the first submit, then I would just like it to keep going with 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, etc..

So the files would look like this:

1000.txt
1001.txt
1002.txt
1003.txt
1004.txt
etc...

This is the PHP-script I'm using:

```
<?php
$nyckel = array(
'privatforetag',
'forefternamn', 
'foretagsnamn', 
'gatuadress', 
'mobil', 
'telefon', 
'e-post', 
'epost', 
'kalender-tidig', 
'kalender-senast', 
'flyttar-fran-gatuadress', 
'flyttar-fran-portkod', 
'flyttar-fran-postadress', 
'boendetyp', 
'meter', 
'hiss', 
'flyttar-till-gatuadress', 
'flyttar-till-postnummer', 
'flyttar-till-portkod', 
'boendetyp2', 
'meter2', 
'hiss2', 
'rum', 
'personer', 
'kontor', 
'moblerat', 
'boyta', 
'biyta', 
'inventarielista', 
'packning', 
'uppackning', 
'inventarie', 
'antalflyttlador', 
'flyttlada', 
'miljostation', 
'flyttstad', 
'magasinering', 
'student', 
'ovriginfo', 
'rekommenderad', 
'hurhittade'
);
foreach ($nyckel as $key) {
    if ($_POST[$key]) {
        $input .= $_POST[$key]. "\t";
    } else {
        $input .= "-\t";
    }
    $thekey .= $key. "\t";
}
$index = 1;
$name = str_replace(" " , "" , $_POST["forefternamn"]);
$filename =  $name . $index . ".txt";
while (file_exists($filename)) {
    $index++;
    $filename =  $name .$index. ".txt";
}
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$filename);
fwrite($handle, $thekey);
fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
fwrite($handle, $input);
fclose($handle);
if (file_exists($filename)) {
 echo "<script>window.location = 'www.domain.com'</script>";
}?>
```

Comment: Are you absolutely tied to this approach? Because IMO a better approach would be to use a hash, i.e. an md5 hash of the current timestamp. But I wouldn't like to suggest a different approach unless you're open to it…

Comment: Or even just use the timestamp (I'm assuming you don't need to obscure the ID if you're planning on using a sequential one). That way sorting etc. would still be really easy if that's something you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database table with a primary key ID field and a name field. Insert the name into the table and retrieve the generated ID. Use this generated ID to name the file.

Comment: This would certainly work, but it's adding in quite a lot of needless IO by using the database (especially if the site doesn't already use a database).

Comment: True. And now that I've actually read the whole question, my answer is now "Use a database".

Comment: This would work, but the customer has been pretty clear they don't want to save the submits in databases..

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:-

```
    $dir='c:/temp/inv/';
    $col=glob( $dir . '*.txt' );
    $tmp=array();
    foreach( $col as $file ) $tmp[]=intval( pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );

    $last=intval( max( $tmp ) );
    $next=( $last+1 ).'.txt';

    echo $next;
```

To continue the idea as requested, and to keep in line with the 'racy' ? comment... how about:-

```
$nyckel = array(
    'privatforetag',
    'forefternamn', 
    'foretagsnamn', 
    /* rest of the elements removed for brevity */
    'student', 
    'ovriginfo', 
    'rekommenderad', 
    'hurhittade'
);

/* Helper function to generate next invoice id */
function getnextinvid( $path=false ){
    if( $path ){
        $col=glob( $path . '*.txt' );
        $tmp=array();
        foreach( $col as $file ) $tmp[]=intval( pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
        $last=intval( max( $tmp ) );
        return $path . ( $last+1 ).'.txt';
    }
    return false;
}

/* Loop through array to get POSTed values */
$thekey=$input=array();
foreach( $nyckel as $key ) {
    $input[]=isset( $_POST[ $key ] ) ? $_POST[ $key ] : '-';
    $thekey[]=$key;
}




/* The output filename / invoice should be sequentially numbered */
$output=getnextinvid('c:/temp/inv/');

if( $output ) {
    /* write your data to the output file */
    $bytes=file_put_contents( $output, implode( "\t", $thekey ) . PHP_EOL . implode( "\t", $input ), FILE_TEXT );

    /* Does the new invoice exist? */
    $exists=file_exists( $output ) ? true : false;

    /* good practice to call this after calls to certain functions */
    clearstatcache();

    /* Redirect - alternatively use javascript as originally */
    if( $exists && $bytes ) header('location: http://www.domain.com');

} else {
    echo 'failed';  
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me how this code would look with the whole file?